# UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert for textfield of UIWebView

Tags: uiwebview, textfield, appearance

How to set the keyboard appearance to UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert that appears whenever I tap on text field of UIWebView? I know how to set it for a textfield placed in normal UIView